# small issue in EGA II Proposition (2.1.9)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

I was reading section 2 in EGA II and I have an issue understanding a little step.

It appears in several propositions, so I will present one instance here. Page 22, proof of Proposition (2.1.9). Since the theorem and proof are somewhat lengthy to copy here, I am only copying the exact sentence, and you can find the full context in the book [here](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?id=PMIHES_1961__8_).

> Notons que, si pour un entier $d\ge n_0$, $f\in S_d$ n'appartient pas à $\mathfrak p_d$, alors, si $\mathfrak p$ existe, $\mathfrak p_m$, pour $m<n_0$, este nécessairement égal à l'ensemble des $x\in S_m$ tels que $f^rx\in\mathfrak p_{m+rd}$, ***sauf pour un nombre fini de valeurs de $r$***."

Now, for the life of me, I cannot understand what's with the *except for finitely many values of $r$*. Maybe it's a language misunderstanding or I am missing something obvious.

Here's my reasoning: if $\mathfrak p$ exists (***si $\mathfrak p$ existe***) with the required properties then, since $d\ge n_0$, $f\notin\mathfrak p_d$ is implies $f\notin\mathfrak p$ (as for $n\ge n_0$, $\mathfrak p\cap S_n=\mathfrak p_n$). Also $m+rd\ge n_0$, hence $\mathfrak p_{m+rd}=\mathfrak p\cap S_{m+rd}$, so $f^rx\in\mathfrak p_{m+rd}\subset\mathfrak p$, so *for any $r$*, $f^rx\in\mathfrak p$ is equivalent to $x\in\mathfrak p$, since $\mathfrak p$ is prime and $f\notin\mathfrak p$; so the statement is true for *all* positive $r$.

I apologize in advance if I am missing something silly. I tried to ignore this and read on, but the argument appeared a few more times later (second time being only a few lines below).

Comment: *... but the argument appeared a few more times later (second time being only a few lines below) ...* where $\mathfrak p$ is not assumed to be (a priori) prime.

Comment: Hi @A.G, thanks for the help. True, $\mathfrak p$ is not assumed prime yet, but $d\ge n_0$ and the _assumed_ condition $2^o$ (and $1^o$) do imply that if $x\in S_m$, then $x\in\mathfrak p$ is _equivalent_ to $f^rx\in\mathfrak p_{m+rd}$ for **all** $r$, no?

Comment: You need $r\geq 1$ since $\mathfrak p_{m}$ is still not defined for $m<n_0$ (in fact it is defined by that condition).

Comment: Thanks @A.G - But $r$ cannot be negative no? (if it could be, what would $f^r$ be for $r<0$?) And then why not just say **for every $r\ge1$** instead of "except for finitely many values of $r$". That's essentially what I am asking above.

Comment: It seems to me that, as you suggest, you can substitute "except for finitely many values of $r$" by "for every $r\geq 0$" and (at other places) "for every $r\geq 1$" along the proof of (2.1.9). Maybe the authors preferred that way in order to stress the non-necessity of computing the explicit $r$ (and computing it again in the proof of 2.3.2.4 a few pages later)? I don't know.